# Error Reference_impl.ts:490 Uncaught TypeError: e._checkNotDeleted is not a function Firebase Realtime

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete from the Firebase

```
 import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app.js";
      import {
        getDatabase,
        ref,
        push,
        onValue,
        remove,
      } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-database.js";

      const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyCUIrO-MDXmcWjwA8owfLJx3JXT021uoh4",
        authDomain: "validation-52b11.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://validation-52b11-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "validation-52b11",
        storageBucket: "validation-52b11.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "743887404432",
        appId: "1:743887404432:web:57ab90038b600ecab30715",
      };

      // Initialize Firebase
      const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      const db = getDatabase(app);
      const productsRef = ref(db, "Products/");


 function addProduct() {
        var product = {
          ID: generateUniqueId(),
          productName: productNameInput.value,
          price: productPriceInput.value,
          img: productIMGInput.files[0] ? productIMGInput.files[0].name : "",
          category: productCategoryInput.value,
          desc: productDescInput.value,
        };

        // Push the new product to the Firebase database
        push(productsRef, product);

        // Clear the form
        clearForm();
      }



function deleteProduct(productId) {
        const productRef = ref(productsRef, productId);
        remove(productRef);
      }
```

Realtime database, but this message always appears when updating and deleting, but the extension works well. What is the reason?

I try any solution on internet but i didn't have solution